# Google reCAPTCHAv2 Returning Null PHP Apache

Tags: php, apache, recaptcha

I have searched all over and cannot find a solution for my issue. My reCAPTCHA always returns null, no matter what configuration I use. It used to work, but recently switched to an EC2 instance and now it does not work. I am using PHP5.6 and Apache.

Below is the previously working code.

Client-Side Code

```
<head>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
...
(Rest of Page)
...
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="action.php">
    ...
    (Actual Form Fields)
    ...
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="PUBLIC_KEY"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
            <button id="buttonSubmit" name="buttonSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="bg-info" style="padding: 8px;">(Information to user)</p>

</form>
```

Server-Side Code

```
if (!(InputExists($input['g-recaptcha-response']))) {
    $validationErrors['g-recaptcha-response'] = "<li>Please indicate check <b>I'm not a robot</b></li>";
} else {
    // Construct the Google verification API request link.
    $params = array();
    $params['secret'] = 'PRIVATE_KEY'; // Secret key
    $params['response'] = urlencode($input['g-recaptcha-response']);
    $params['remoteip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $params_string = http_build_query($params);
    $requestURL = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?' . $params_string;

    // Get cURL resource
    $curl = curl_init();

    // Set some options
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $requestURL,
    ));

    // Send the request
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    // Close request
    curl_close($curl);

    $response = @json_decode($response, true);

    if ($response["success"] != true) {
        $validationErrors['g-recaptcha-response'] = "reCAPTCHA error!";
    }

}
```

PUBLIC_KEY and PRIVATE_KEY were removed for this post. As I mentioned, doing var_dump($response) returns NULL and I have checked that my server will handle JSON. I have no idea why it is not working now and have tried every other method I have found, including using the POST and POSTFIELDS options in curl. Is it possible there is a configuration issue with my server? Or is there any other way I can fix this? Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's inside `$response`?

Comment: Inside $response is NULL

Comment: Then check curl errors with `curl_error`.

Comment: curl_error outputs Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized. So, I added the path to the cert using cainfo, now there is no curl error and the response is still NULL

Comment: However, if I test with verify_peer off I get a success response.

Comment: Now I'd use wireshark/tcpdump to see what actually is requested and what response is received. There is certainly something with TLS and the traffic dump would reveal the actual problem.

Comment: It looks as though the server is sending SYN, which is being returned by google with SYN and ACK. This is being ACK by server and followed by a FIN and ACK. Then is ACK by google, then FIN and ACK, ending the exchange. This is all happening over the appropriate port. I am not too experienced with tcpdump and cannot really tell what type of exchange is going on in terms of certificates and such. Google doesn't recognize the certificate being sent? Any comment as to any of that?

Comment: "Google doesn't recognize the certificate being sent? " --- in your explanation the TLS handshake step is missing though,

Comment: I see, I'm sorry as I said I am not experienced with tcpdump, what am I looking for to indicate the TLS handshake? Also, I really appreciate all of the help so far.

Comment: I believe I found the handshake, with each server PUSH and ACK each other. I used this command that I found on stack overflow: tcpdump -ni eth0 "tcp port 443 and (tcp[((tcp[12] & 0xf0) >> 2)] = 0x16)" and it outputs this line from server to google: Flags [P.], seq 3845145533:3845145736, ack 4076969921, win 211, options [nop,nop,TS val 86897652 ecr 635803696], length 203     and this line from google to server: Flags [P.], seq 1:3181, ack 203, win 170, options [nop,nop,TS val 635803830 ecr 86897652], length 3180